# webpack dev is not displaying the application

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-universal

I am working with Angular Universal + CLI and my package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod && ngc && webpack",
    "start:dev":"webpack-dev-server --inline --progress",
    "production": "node dist/server.js"
  }
```

If I run npm run build:prod my application is running on localhost:4000 with npm run production.

But if I run npm run start:dev after the application is completed and I run localhost:8080 I just see this site:
[image]

I want to use the change detection without that I always need to build from everything which take much time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of angular cli is to run your app using those cli commands. Try first to check your npm & cli version (npm -v and ng -v)

If your ng -v shows you all your packages, then you should run ng build --prod instead of npm. Ng use npm to build your app, but does not pass the same argument & parameters.

Once you have angular cli installed (ng command and angular@cli module), then simply use ng as your main command lines. Only use npm for package install (npm i)

Comment: As I described  - In build:prod it is working fine. It is not a problem with angular cli. I need to use web dev server instead webpack

Comment: Ok got it ! Webpack creates you a bundle which is used for the webserver or local server. So in your case, you want to use your webpack, but did you specify the port ?webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080

Comment: No I didn't. It is running by default in port localhost:8080